# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dispatch is not a function useContext/useReducer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am new to react. I am working on a blogging website in which I need to create a login page. I am facing the following error:

> TypeError: dispatch is not a function

Following is my code to handle submit and request to the API. I am getting

```
const { dispatch, isFetching } = useContext(Context);
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_START" });
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5001/api/auth/login", {
        username: userRef.current.value,
        password: passwordRef.current.value,
      });
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE" });
    }
  };
```

Following is my code of the form:

```
return (
    <div className="login">
      <span className="loginTitle">Login</span>
      <form className="loginForm" onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="loginInput"
          placeholder="Enter your username..."
          ref={userRef}
        />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          className="loginInput"
          placeholder="Enter your password..."
          ref={passwordRef}
        />
        <button className="loginButton" type="submit" disabled={isFetching}>
          Login
        </button>
      </form>
      <button className="loginRegisterButton">
        <Link className="link" to="/register">
          Register
        </Link>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

Following is the Context Provider

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import Reducer from "./Reducer";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null,
  isFetching: false,
  error: false,
};

export const Context = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, INITIAL_STATE);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.user));
  }, [state.user]);

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        user: state.user,
        isFetching: state.isFetching,
        error: state.error,
        dispatch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

Following is my app.js with all the root nodes in it

```
import Home from "./Pages/home/Home";
import TopBar from "./components/topbar/TopBar";
import Single from "./Pages/single/Single";
import Write from "./Pages/write/Write";
import Settings from "./Pages/settings/Settings";
import Login from "./Pages/login/Login";
import Register from "./Pages/register/Register";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Context } from "./context/Context";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  BrowserRouter
} from "react-router-dom"

function App() {
  const { user } = useContext(Context);
  return (
    <BrowserRouter >
      <TopBar />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="register" element={user ? <Home /> : <Register />} />
        <Route path="login" element={ user ? <Home /> : <Login />} />
        <Route path="write" element={user ? <Write /> : <Register />} />
        <Route path="settings" element={user ? <Settings /> : <Register />} />
        <Route path="post/:postId" element={<Single />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter >
  );
}

export default App;
```

Can somebody please help me out with this.

Comment: Do you have a line earlier in the component that looks like `const dispatch = useDispatch()`?

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the notice.I am editing the question and it is: const { dispatch, isFetching } = useContext(Context);

Comment: Ok, make sure to show us the `<Context.Provider>` too, since you're doing something custom

Comment: Added the same.

Comment: Thanks. And where is the context provider relative to the context consumer? The provider needs to be higher up the component tree than the consumer. If not, you will get the default value of the context, which would cause exactly the error you're seeing (since the default value has no dispatch function).

Comment: In other words: the component with `const { dispatch, isFetching } = useContext(Context);` must be a descendant of `<ContextProvider>`.

Comment: I am getting it in the following line: dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_START" });. This line will be called upon when the user clicks a button in the form which you can see in the return function. Context is being set upon based on the API result. So, technically it is in the initial state but only being called upon when the user clicks a button. I am new to this, may or may have not been able to understand what you are saying.

Comment: I've added an answer which hopefully should point you in the right direction. The problem is about the tree of components. I don't know exactly what your tree looks like, so i gave some examples.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Got it. Had to do the same as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are apparently getting the default value from the context, and your default value does not have a `dispatch` function. For context to work, there must be a context provider higher up the component tree than the component that's trying to consume context.

You are either not rendering a ContextProvider at all, or you are rendering it in the wrong part of the component tree.

For example, the following will work:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <MyForm />
    <ContextProvider>
  ) 
}

const MyForm = () => {
  const { dispatch, isFetching } = useContext(Context);
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
     // ...
  }

  return (
    <div className="login">
      // ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

But this will not (the provider is a child of the consumer):

```
const MyForm = () => {
  const { dispatch, isFetching } = useContext(Context);
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
     // ...
  }

  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <div className="login">
        // ...
      </div>
    </ContextProvider>
  )
}
```

And neither will this (the provider exists, but isn't an ancestor of MyForm)

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyForm />
      <ContextProvider />
    </div>
  )
}
```